# AngularJS : How to write unit test of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, unit-testing, jasmine

Pardon me If I am repeating this question.
I am very new to AngularJS and Unit test cases with jasmine. I have started playing with angularJs very recently. I have gone through so many articles but I couldn't get any help. 
I want to write Jasmine unit test case for the below controller.

```js
intelApp.controller('healthIndexCtrl', [ '$scope','$http','$filter','deviceService', '$controller','$localStorage','getSensorDetails', function ($scope,$http,$filter,deviceService,$controller,$localStorage,getSensorDetails) {
 //device variable declaration
 $scope.device = {
   status : 'OFF',
   statusColor : 'red',
   id : '',
   parameterValues : [],
   trendChart : {
   currentChartData : ''
   }
    };
 $scope.markers = [];
 $scope.devices=[];
 $scope.sensorData=[];
 $scope.isAnamolies='';
 $scope.pagination=true;
 $scope.tab2Show=false;
 //====================================Map functions==================================
 
 var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 4,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
     }
     $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  
 var createMarker = function (info) {
    
    //set image depends on status
    var markerIcon='';
    if(info.status=='Green'){
   markerIcon='assets/images/green-dot.png';
    }else if(info.status=='Yellow')
    {
   markerIcon='assets/images/yellow-dot.png'
    }
    else{
  markerIcon='assets/images/red-dot.png';
    }
    
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( info.latitude,  info.longitude),
   icon:markerIcon,
            title: info.city,
            Name:info.name
        });
       
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
           infoWindow.setContent('<h4>Device Information</h4>Device Name : ' + marker.Name +'<br>DeviceType : ' +info.deviceType + '<br>Description : '+info.deviceDesc);
           infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
           $scope.information=true;
       });
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
   $scope.trendchart(info.name);
    });
    
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
   infoWindow.close();
    });
            
         $scope.markers.push(marker);
         
    }
 
 $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }
  
 $scope.clearMarkers = function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
         $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
       }
       $scope.markers.length = 0;
     }
 $scope.zoomToIncludeMarkers = function() {
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  console.log($scope.devices);
       $scope.devices.forEach(function(device) {
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(device.latitude,device.longitude);
          bounds.extend(latLng);
        });
           
          $scope.map.fitBounds(bounds);
     }
 
   $("#mapCanvas").on('shown.bs.tab', function() {
    $scope.tab2Show=false;
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    $scope.zoomToIncludeMarkers();
    $scope.$apply();
    });
   
     $("#deviceList").on('shown.bs.tab', function() {
    $scope.tab2Show=false;
    $("#mytable tr").removeClass('selected');
   $scope.$apply();
    });
   
  //=============================Map ends here======================================
 

 /**
  * $on function gives the filtered devices on healthindex page
  */
 $scope.$on('passListToHealthIndex', function( event , obj){
  $scope.deviceListShow=true;
     $scope.pagination=obj.devices.length>0?false:true;
     $scope.tab2Show=false;
     $scope.warningShow=false;
     $scope.devices = obj.devices;
  console.log($scope.devices);
     //Plot marker for maps
    for(i=0;i<$scope.devices.length;i++){
   createMarker($scope.devices[i]);
   $scope.zoomToIncludeMarkers();
   }
     
     //Pagination settings
     $scope.viewby = 5;
  $scope.totalItems = $scope.devices.length;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
  $scope.maxSize = 2; // Number of pager buttons to show  
  $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {$scope.currentPage = pageNo;  };
  $scope.pageChanged = function() {
   };
    $scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
     $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
     $scope.currentPage = 1; // reset to first paghe
    }
 });
 
 
 //===============================Trend Chart ==============================
 //Function gets the sensor details, displays and visualize trend data in the line chart form 
 $scope.trendchart=function(deviceName){
     for(var cnt=0;cnt<$scope.devices.id;cnt++){
   try{
   document.getElementById('trendChart'+cnt).innerHTML= '&nbsp;';
   }catch(e){
   }
    }
      $("#mytable tr").click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
       var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();    
     });

      $('.ok').on('click', function(e){
        alert($("#table tr.selected td:first").html());
     });
     
     
      
 /**
  * @HTTP GET to get sensor details
  * @param deviceName 
  *@returns sensor details
  */
  
  getSensorDetails.query({vending_machine_id:deviceName},function(RESPONSE){
   $scope.sensorData=RESPONSE.data;
   $scope.device.parameterValues = $scope.sensorData.sensors;
   
   $scope.tab2Show=$scope.device.parameterValues.length>0?true:false;
    
   var temp=$filter('filter')($scope.devices, {deviceId:deviceName})[0];
   $scope.isAnamolies=temp.status;
   
   if($scope.isAnamolies=='Yellow'){
    $scope.warningShow=true;
   }else{
    $scope.warningShow=false;
   }
   
   $scope.$apply();
   //Draw trendchart for each sensors
   for(var i=0;i<$scope.sensorData.sensors.length;i++){
    drawTrendChart($scope.sensorData.sensors[i],"#trendChart"+i,$scope,"Time",$scope.sensorData.sensors[i].details.sensorName);
    jQuery("#trendChart"+i).tooltip();
   }
      
     
  });
  
 }
  //Function to search device based on given searchString from devicelist
  $scope.searchForDevice = function(arr, searchString){
   if(!searchString){
    return arr;
   } 
   var result = [];
   searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
   angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
    if(item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) != -1){
     result.push(item);
    } 
   });
   return result;
 }
   //watches model "deviceSearchString" to get new values
  $scope.$watch('deviceSearchString', function (newVal, oldVal) {
   $scope.filteredDevices = $scope.searchForDevice($scope.devices, newVal);
   $scope.totalItems = $scope.filteredDevices.length;
   $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.itemsPerPage);
   $scope.currentPage = 1;
  }, true);
  
  //navigate to login page when you click on logout option in navigation
  $scope.logout = function(){
   window.location = "index.html"
   }     
  
 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Here "**getSensorDetails**" is factory service which uses $resouce for REST service.

```js
intelApp.factory('getSensorDetails',function($resource){
 return $resource('http://retail-test-intelapiapp.demo-gotapaas.com/intel/sensorvalues',{},{
 // return $resource('https://10.47.32.62:8244/deviceParameters/v1.0/sensorvalues',{},{
 query: {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function(data, headers){
            response = {};
   /*var temp=data.trim();
   temp=temp.substring(1,data.length-2);
   temp= temp.replace(/\\/g, "");*/
            response.data = JSON.parse(data);
            response.headers = headers();
            return response;
        }
 }});
});
```

I know how to write unit test case for straight functions but this controller shows more than that. 
It would be good if anyone can show how to write Unit test case for controller.

Thanks in Adavance
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at these, http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html
http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/jasmine.html
This links might help you to understand better.

Its hard to explain, I'll give it a try.

A test should start with a describe with explain what you are going to cover, like:

```
describe('healthIndexCtrl', function () {
});
```

Then inside this function you should load your controller and the dependent file like,

```
beforeEach(module('app.module.modulename')); // this is the module name of your controller.
```

Now the controller will start running.

Then you need to inject the dependencies you used in controller to the test like below

```
var scope, http, filter, deviceService, controller, localStorage, getSensorDetails;
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $http, $filter, deviceService, $controller, $localStorage, getSensorDetails) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    http = $http;
    deviceService = deviceService;
    controller = $controller;
    localStorage = $localStorage;
    getSensorDetails = getSensorDetails;
}));
```

Note: You have inject only the dependency you are going to in spec file not all you used in controller.

Then if you are hitting and backend or you need to mock a factory response, you can use spyOn() for faking the hit and give a mocked response like below.

spyOn(getSensorDetails, 'query').and.returnValue('mock the response you want. Can be any datatype even object or arrays');

Then finally you can write your expect() in it(), like

```
it('some message', function () {
   scope.$digest();
   expect(scope.map).toBe('some mock');
});
```

we are using scope.$digest(); so that the $scope in the controller will update with your mocks in spec.

So finally, putting all together, your spec looks like this,

```
describe('healthIndexCtrl', function () {
    beforeEach(module('app.module.modulename'));

    var scope, http, filter, deviceService, controller, localStorage, getSensorDetails;
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $http, $filter, deviceService, $controller, $localStorage, getSensorDetails) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        http = $http;
        deviceService = deviceService;
        controller = $controller;
        localStorage = $localStorage;
        getSensorDetails = getSensorDetails;
     }));

     it('some message', function () {
        scope.$digest();
        expect(scope.map).toBe('some mock');
     });

});
```

Hope this will help.